# Search Bar in the Ubuntu Software App is hidden!

Tags: software-center

I'm a returning user off linux,
I used it for a few years and then had to use windows for a few years because most of the college work I had involved some sort of software or another that obliged me to use the MS environment.
Now, after 4 years, I reinstalled my favorite OS to find that I'm clueless of how to work with it again.

why I can't get to have a search bar on the Ubuntu software store?

Comment: Search bar is revealed when you press the Super key (Windows key)

Comment: Disregard previous comment: at first, I misunderstood your issue.

Comment: Don't you have a search icon at the top left of the header bar?

Answer (score 2):

The search bar is hidden indeed. However, the search field immediately will appear as soon as you start typing a seach, allowing for an immediate search as soon as you have launched the software center.

Answer (score 1):

It is hidden. This worked on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) for me :

To turn the search bar on just do: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>

If you want to hide it then press: <kbd>Esc</kbd>

Note: It will disappear every time you click on something, to make the search again available, just do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> as shown above.

:)